# "Document1" created in addition to new document each time

Tags: document-library, document, document-template

Each time I select the **New Document** drop-down in the ribbon and a new document is created, I also end up with a document called **Document1**.

I think it may have something to do with the settings for the content types. I could see any settings that looked like they may have a bearing on this though.

Has anybody experienced similar issues with this?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any custom event receivers or workflows associated with the library?

Comment: What content type is asscociated with the library?

Comment: try to change the document-templatefile format from ".dotx" to ".dot"

Comment: No workflows associated with the library @JussiPalo

Comment: @HarryB - we have a range of content types and templates associated with the library.

Comment: What is the default content type?

Comment: @HarryB It's a word document in all of our libraries. I should not it's a different word template in each one though.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this issue is rectified by choosing **Save as** in Word Online and then opting to **Rename**. The "Document 1" is generated when you choose to save as, as Word Online has already auto saved the "Document 1" and your new document becomes a separate document.